# Keeping R Notebook table format when knitting

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Within R Notebooks, when printing an object, the Notebook will display the data.frame in a very clean & clear manner, with scroll-able features. However, when the document is knitted as an html output, Rmarkdown will display it differently. Two key features that I would like to capture within this table:

- The column types / classes (character / factor / double etc)
- If a column contains a list structure, the class of the underlying data in that column

Any code I can add in front of the object to obtain the same features as in a R Notebook?

Below an example:

```
ldata <- 26
xts_list <- replicate(ldata,xts(rnorm(ldata),order.by = seq(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date() + 25,1)),simplify = FALSE)

tibble(A = LETTERS,
   B = 1:ldata,
   C = letters,
   D = rnorm(ldata),
   E = colors()[1:ldata],
   F = sample(month.abb,ldata,replace = TRUE),
   G = xts_list)
```

Output in R Notebook when running the chunk:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends what your output is. If you knit to an html page, the easiest way to achieve what you see in R notebooks is to use the `DT` library:

```
library(DT)
datatable(cars)
```

Using your toy data in an Rmd, you get the following output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @DeveauP, thanks. Yes, aware of DT package. And certainly one way to do this. This does not capture though the types / classes of data per column that you see at the top of each column.  And also not the list structure that might be apparent in a data.frame.  Let me add some more content to the question.